# Is there any tool to find any difference between two xcode projects?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any tool available to find the difference between two versions of same xcode project?. So that I can easily get an overview of the changed/newly-added/deleted files.

Thanks,
durai.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The Xcode tools include the FileMerge.app application that does exactly what you're looking for.

[image]

[image]

It's at `<Developer Tools>/Applications/Utilities/FileMerge.app`.

Comment: As of Xcode 4.5, you can open FileMerge by right clicking Xcode > Open Developer Tool > FileMerge.

Answer (score 15):

You can compare two Xcode project using FileMerge tool available with Xcode.

Below are steps for comparison in Xcode 6.1

1. Right click on **Xcode icon** -> Select '**Open Developer Tool**' -> Select '**FileMerge**' option

[image: Screenshot 0]

2. This will open window as show below :

[image: Screenshot 1]

3. Select two Xcode project which is to be compared by clicking **Left and Right button**
4. Click on '**Compare**' button. This will create list of file that are added, removed or altered
   by comparing two Xcode project.

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Note :** *While selecting file for Left/Right go to folder level not Xcode file or workspace*

You can check `changes in Left/Right,` `identical between Left/Right` or `Added/Deleted` by selecting feature present in extreme right side of window (if using Xcode 8.2.1)

[image: screenshot 4]

Comment: You are perfect mate :)))

Comment: Thanks @Ucdemir. Do upvote if you like answer!!

Comment: I have already did